# Realex payment integration - remote method

Tags: php, realex-payments-api

I'm doing a website with Realex as the payment gateway. I want to integrate remote realex payment method in my website.

I know when we go live we need SSL enabled on our website to do remote method payments. But my question is, Is SSL required when we are doing testing?

Every time I test, it results in error (remote method), but when I do Real Auth method there is no problem.

I don't know what the exact problem is. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

No. We use Realex, and don't use SSL on our test sites.

In fact, if we don't use SSL on our live sites, it still generates no error. Realex doesn't actually have any way to know whether or not you're using SSL.

Answer (score 0):

As TRiG has already said, Realex have no way of telling whether or not you have SSL on your website. However, your customers will not feel safe entering card details if they don't see the little padlock, and this will affect your sales conversion.

Communications between your server and Realex are https/SSL, so this is secure, but the card data must first get from the browser to your server securely. You may prefer to use the Realex Redirect integration if you do not want to buy an SSL cert.

Owen

Answer (score 0):

at merchant site in live / testing ssl is not required

it  results in error . may be due to 
your response URL is not set 
or you are trying to get the response from local host

to set  response URL have to contact Realex support ...

it is the same as we do in papal notify
what response URL we send that is to compare not to set